# Product of inverse cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

> Let $\epsilon =(13524)$ and $B=(13)(25)$. Compute $B^{-1}\epsilon B$.

I done the problem and got this.

$(52)(31)(13524)(13)(25)=(12)(3)(45)$

Am I on the right track or is this wrong?

Comment: The inverse of a product of disjoint transpositions is it itself...

Comment: You may find the following question useful http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274649/what-do-cycle-decompositions-mean/275060#275060

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to calculate the product $(52)(31)(13524)(13)(25)$, I do the following:

Start with $1$: The first parenthesis (read right to left) does not do anything to $1$ since $(25)$ only switches those two numbers. The second parenthensis sends you to $3$ (so remember, you are now $3$), the next parenthesis send you to $5$ (since it is right the the $3$ which is your current value), so you are at $5$, the next parenthesis is a $(31)$ so it doesnt do anything to you, and the last one is $(52)$, so it sends you to $2$. Hence, $1$ got sent to $2$.

Now we check where does $2$ get sent: First parenthesis sends you to $5$, next one doesnt do anything, so you are at $5$ now, the next parenthesis doesnt do anything to $5$, the next parenthesis sends $5$ to $2$, the next one nothing, and the last one sends you from $2$ to $5$. Hence in total you have that $2$ goes to $5$.

Hence, the beginning of your cycle starts like $(125...)$. To fill the blank to the same with $5$ to see where it goes, and so on.

I tried to literally write in plain english what goes through my head when I multiply cycles. I hope its helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how you got that, but conjugation doesn't change the cycle type.  You have that $(5 \ 2)(3 \ 1)(1 \ 3 \ 5 \ 2 \ 4)(1 \ 3)(2 \ 5)$ sends $3$ to $3$, but in fact it sends $3$ to $1$:

$$\begin{align} [(5 \ 2)(3 \ 1)(1 \ 3 \ 5 \ 2 \ 4)(1 \ 3)(2 \ 5)](3) &= [(5 \ 2)(3 \ 1)(1 \ 3 \ 5 \ 2 \ 4)(1 \ 3)](3) \\ &= [(5 \ 2)(3 \ 1)(1 \ 3 \ 5 \ 2 \ 4)](1) \\ &= [(5 \ 2)(3 \ 1)(3) \\ &= [(5 \ 2)](1) \\ &= 1\end{align}$$

More generally, if $(a \ b \ c \ \cdots)$ is a cycle and $\sigma$ is a permutation then $\sigma(a \ b \ c \ \cdots)\sigma^{-1}$ is the cycle $(\sigma(a) \ \sigma(b) \ \sigma(c) \ \cdots)$.

Answer (score 3):

> For permutations $x,y\in S_n$ where $x=(\xi_1,\xi_2,\cdots,\xi_n)$ we have $$y^{-1}xy=(\xi_1^y,\xi_2^y,\cdots,\xi_n^y)$$

So, here, we have:

$$B^{-1}\epsilon B=(1,2,5,4,3)$$ Note that $B^{-1}=B$, here.

Answer (score 3):

> Let $\epsilon=(13524)$ and $B=(13)(25)$. Compute $B^{-1}\epsilon B$.

First, note that $B^{-1} = (52)(31) = (25)(13)$ and since this the product of disjoint cycles commutes, in fact, $(25)(13) = (13)(25) = B$.

Now, in your setup of $B^{-1}\epsilon B = (52)(31)(13524)(13)(25)$, we have what is known as the conjugation of $\epsilon$ by $B$: $B^{-1}\epsilon B$, and conjugation of a permutation $\alpha$ by any element in $S_n$ leaves the *cycle structure* of $\alpha$ *unchanged*. In this case, that means that since $\epsilon$ is a $5$-cycle, so too will be $B^{-1}\epsilon B$:

$$B^{-1}\epsilon B = (52)(31)(13524)(13)(25) = (1\,2\,5\,4\,3),\;\;\text{a}\;5\text{-cycle, too}$$

Comment: Getting back into Abs Alg, excellent! +1

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks! I do love abstract algebra, and especially groups :-)